# How to limit User access to a User API to it's own :ID only?

Tags: strapi

I have created an API that contains many pieces of information related to each "User". By default "User" only have a model containing e-mail, password, username and lang.
So I have created a "UserInfo" API/Model that contains firstName, lastName, age, address and so on.
I want to give non-admin users access to it's own "UserInfo" data, which means the user would be able to access the api using localhost/userinfo/:id. But each user will only get authorized to call it's own ID and not other users IDs.
How can I create such a "policy"/ restriction for the final users "role"?
Hope I have been clear enough. My questions is probably quite trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play with role's permissions or policies.
I think this issue is really close to what you want: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/624

Answer (score 1):

In strapi after the authentication the ctx.state.user.id is assigned with the user entity so you can use it to validate.

you can either create a policy

```
module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  const { params } = ctx;
  if (ctx.state.user.id === params.id) {
    return next();
  } else {
    return ctx.badRequest(
      'Not Authorized'
    );
  }
};
```

and set policy in the route file

```
{
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/userinfo/:id",
      "handler": "userinfo.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": [ 
            "admin::hasPermissions",
"isOwner"]
      }
    }
```

Or custom write the findOne method

```
async findOne(ctx) {
  const { query, params } = ctx;
  if (ctx.state.user.id === params.id) {
    const entity = await service.findOne({ ...query, id: params.id });
  }
  else {
    return ctx.badRequest(
      'Not Authorized'
    )
  }

  return sanitize(entity);
},
```